# Animation not running in Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have some code that runs in Spyder, however when I try to run it in Jupiter notebook it doesn't work (I've tried putting %matplot lib at the top of the cell but I just get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower')
This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import animation
def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
   return (vmax - vmin) * np.random.rand(n) + vmin
n = 100
xx = randrange(n, 23, 32)
yy = randrange(n, 0, 100)
zz = randrange(n, -50, -25)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)


def init():
    ax.scatter(xx, yy, zz, marker='o', s=20, c="goldenrod", alpha=0.6)
    return fig,

def animate(i):
    ax.view_init(elev=10., azim=i)
    return fig,

# Animate
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=360, interval=20, blit=True)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Jupiter environment does not have the ability to render animations, so it seems to use the HTML video function. I am jupyterLab and I always run with this.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import animation
from IPython.display import HTML # updated

def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    return (vmax - vmin) * np.random.rand(n) + vmin

n = 100
xx = randrange(n, 23, 32)
yy = randrange(n, 0, 100)
zz = randrange(n, -50, -25)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)


def init():
    ax.scatter(xx, yy, zz, marker='o', s=20, c="goldenrod", alpha=0.6)
    return fig,

def animate(i):
    ax.view_init(elev=10., azim=i)
    return fig,

# Animate
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=360, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.close() # updated
HTML(anim.to_html5_video()) # updated
```

Comment: do you have something installed to avoid this error:RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available

Comment: To create a GIF image, I use the following. `from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter;
anim.save('file_name.gif', writer='pillow')` I also use this setting in ffmpeg for videos.`anim.save('file_name.mp4', writer='ffmpeg', fps=30) `

Comment: You can find the ffmpeg installation [here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Comment: cheers ill install it, so theres definitely no way to get animations to run without it? I thought it had something to do with the fact the the cells were automatically set to inline but wasn't sure what the equivalent of "inline" was for cells with moving animations.

Comment: ffmpeg is used when you want to save an animation as a video. It is not required for animation. The last code is to display the created animation as a video in HTML5.

Comment: so you're able to run the code you've provided without ffmpeg on Jupiter notebook?

Comment: My runtime environment is jupyterLab, and I have checked the execution without ffmpeg. My code should also work on notebooks.

Comment: Sorry was at work, I tried it on Jupyterlab and it still asks for ffmpeg player :/

Comment: Does my code require me to install ffmpeg? I don't think so. I've put my code on [google Colabratory](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15aj1dZkmceoiJqxc0pAFio0S3mJLzdhZ?usp=sharing). Please try to run it.